# Import Certificates into keystore, certificate chain is null

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keystore, keytool

We are currently developing a java client app, which communicates with a 
server via ssl-secured connection. Our design requires the server to 
authenticate against the client by using a trusted certificate. The 
certificate-chain looks like this:

```
<SOME CA Root certificate>
+- <SOME CA Intermediate certificate>
   +- <Our companies certificate>
```

Initially, we thought this to be simple: Generate an arbitrary empty keystore, 
import CA-root, CA-intermediate and finally our own certificate, distribute 
this keystore among the clients and done. To do so, we used pem-files 
containing the signed public key. Importing the CA-Root-Key we told the 
keystore to mark that as trusted.

However, every access to `keystore.getCertificateChain` returns `null`.

We have checked via `keytool` and `KeyStoreExplorer` that all certificates are 
available in the keystore as expected (they are) and also, that the 
key-identifiers of respective subject and authority-key match (they do). We 
also made sure that the imports where done in the correct order: first CA, 
then intermediate, then our companies certificate.

We went to our own companies website (where firefox says, the certificate is 
good) and downloaded the whole certificate chain (as pem) from there to rule 
out, that the original pem-files are corrupt, yet nothing changes.

Where did we go wrong? Do we have to explicitly set the certificate-chain? How 
can we get details, which step within `getCertificateChain` is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the root certificate of the chain as a trusted CA certificate. Not the whole chain. And `KeyStore.getCertificateChain()` only applies to private key entries, which this isn't.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! That's why I couldn't find a solution